# Storage Limit for Amazon EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a web application on AWS EC2 server. Now I need to send some images to the server and store. Can anyone please tell me if there is a size limit to storing files in the EC2 server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the storage to survive a restart you'll have to mount an [EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) volume.  An EBS volume can be up to 1TB.  You can attach up to 20 EBS volumes to an instance, which will give you ~20TB worth of storage.

If you need that much data you might also want to consider [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), which is theoretically unlimited but it requires you to work with the S3 API rather than directly with a filestystem.

Comment: currently according to their current documentation EBS is able to scale unlimited as well; if u attach more EBS volumes
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/volume_constraints.html#ebs-storage-capacity

Comment: but i think OP is asking about Instance storage, which is inbuilt to the ec2 instance ; which depends on the instance type;
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-store-volumes.html

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there is a hard limit from the EC2 layer itself. However you should consider the following points:

- is there a web server configuration for maximum allowed upload size?
- is there a server-side language configuration for maximum allowed size?
- is there a filesystem limit?
- or: if you store the images in a database, is there a limit?
- is there an operating system limit?

Without knowing more about your application (e.g. the programing language, server software etc) it is hard to give a general answer. However for "normal images" and "normal applications", you should probably only look into the first two points given :)

Comment: My doubt is, since EC2 is meant for computing and S3 is meant for storage, will Amazon be putting a restriction on the amount of data I can store on EC2 server?